# need find from text all "src" elements

Tags: php, preg-match

i need get from text all "src" elements. "src" can have " or '.
Text found in the well, but if element have id, style... They also grabbed.
I need only src value.

My code:

```
$html = 'text text <img src="img1.png"/> as as <img src=\'second.gif\' id ="test" /> as';

preg_match_all('/src=("|\')([^"]*)("|\')/', $html, $htmlSrc);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($htmlSrc);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => src="img1.png"
            [1] => src='second.gif' id ="
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
            [1] => '
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => img1.png
            [1] => second.gif' id =
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
            [1] => "
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is a bad idea and you will probably end up with unmaintainable and unreliable code. It would be easy and reliable if you use an HTML parser. You can find an example here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, but for one query why load this big library.

Comment: I cannot know how many times you are using it :) This is just a solution.

Comment: I like this library, it is very good, especially for this kind of things. But sometimes you just want to have a simple fix for a simple problem. Regexes are nice for that kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/src="|\'([^"\']*)"|\'/', $html, $htmlSrc);
print_r($htmlSrc[2]);
```

Seems to work better.